# how to install OpenBR

Tags: openbr

I want to install openbr in windows. I use `VS2015` and `Qt5.8` and `CMake3.7win64x64` and `opencv3.2`.  (in http://openbiometrics.org/docs/install/index.html#windows has pointed use VS2013, OpenCV2.4.11, Qt5.4.1 but i don't know, the problem relate to versions or not?!) when i type:
`cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` 
in `VS2015x86x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` 
i get this error:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should send as comment but I cannot.
I tried OpenBR yesterday and face some version problem,too. But In your question, It seems it is the problem of Building openCV.

I saw that your error message is the same as your command. Is there any copy-paste error?

Since this step seems nothing to do with QT, I used VS2015, openCV3.0 and cmake 3.5.1

what I did is:

1. mkdir build-msvc2015
2. cd build-msvc2015
3. cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

and worked fine. It would face some problem if you don't cd to the folder or the folder have already something in that.So I think the later version of openCV and visual studio would be fine in this step.

Comment: thanks. I solved this problem. i hadn't downloaded opencv2.4.11 that offer http://openbiometrics.org  and so CMakeLists.txt was not in this folder. after that i downloaded [OpenCV 2.4.11](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.11/opencv-2.4.11.zip/download) my problem is solved.

Comment: but i have other question. when i build OpenBR on windows and when i type following code on `VS2015 x86 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` : `cmake -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/opencv-2.4.11/build/install;C:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/msvc2013_64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install" -DBR_INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` i get this error : `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/opncv2.4.11/../OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.`

Comment: it seems that your cmake cannot find your opencv, two possible solutions: 1.the path of opencv is wrong. the path in the document was wrong, it build opencv in the C:/open-2.4.11/build-msvc2013/ , but it search the opencv in the C:/open-2.4.11/build, so it cannot find it. 2.add OpenCV_DIR to your environment variables, variable name: OpenCV_DIR variable value: the build folder of your opencv(ex:C:/open-2.4.11/build). I don't know why but it worked for me even if i give wrong opencv path to cmake